# Can't use Python virtualenv on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv

I'm having trouble with Python virtualenv on OSX. After creating a virtualenv and doing a `pip freeze` it says it's got a long list of things installed, which are actually the things I've got installed on my main pip installation (outside of the virtualenv):

```
kramer65$ virtualenv venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
kramer65$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)kramer65$ which pip
/Users/kramer65/repos/venv/bin/pip
(venv)kramer65$ pip freeze
apns==2.0.1
APScheduler==3.0.4
argh==0.26.1
Babel==1.3
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
etc.
etc.
```

I've got virtualenv version 13.1.2, which I think is the latest.

So to be sure I tried calling pip with a direct link, but that gives the same result:

```
(venv)kramer65$ ./venv/bin/pip freeze
apns==2.0.1
APScheduler==3.0.4
etc.
etc.
```

or even by calling pip with the virtualenv python:

```
(venv)kramer65$ ./venv/bin/python venv/bin/pip freeze
apns==2.0.1
APScheduler==3.0.4
etc.
etc.
```

I also uninstalled and reinstalled virtualenv, but with the same result. Does anybody know why I can't seem to be able to call the Python of the installed virtualenv? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]

As per the suggestion of @sushant below I tried using `--no-site-packages`:

```
kramer65$ virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
kramer65$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)kramer65$ pip freeze
apns==2.0.1
APScheduler==3.0.4
argh==0.26.1
Babel==1.3
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
etc.
etc.
(venv)kramer65$ which pip
/Users/kramer65/repos/venv/bin/pip
```

Comment: what does `which python` show?

Comment: @scytale - `which python` shows `/Users/kramer65/repos/venv/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `virtualenv` installation is include main `site-packages` too.

`virtualenv` will not include `site-packages` if you invoke it like so:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but this is unfortunately not the case. Also, on a Linux host I've got no problem with this. If I setup a new virtualenv on Linux and do a `pip freeze` I only get `wheel==0.24.0` being installed.